# Comparing impact of variable in a category for a given sample data

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am a software engineer and I have been asked to look at some performance issues that we are having with some batch-jobs on a system I am working on.

The batch jobs generate data for different categories (A-Z), however the mix of categories varies depending on the time of day. The job is run 5 times a day. The total amount of data per job is approximately 2,000 entries, with a different mixture of categories (e.g. the 9am job has roughly 200 category B's, 1200 category A's and 600 category C's). I also have recorded the total runtime of the job, however I need a way of estimating/approximating the time it takes an individual data point for each category to run.

I have data that shows the category (A-Z) for each run of the job (1-5) for the past 30 days. From using pivot tables I am pretty sure that a particular category affects the performance of the 9am job (the other jobs have no entries for this category and run well), however I need a way of "proving" this.

I am unsure about how I should go about this. As I said, I can use a pivot chart to show that there are a lot of category B entries in the 9am job, however I would prefer some mathematically accurate way of supporting this hypothesis.

Thankyou for your help.

Aidos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may well be a better way to go about this but if you simply add all the entries from each job with the average time per entry for each job. You can then compute the average time per entry for each category. Not perfect, but differences between the average time for an entry in each category should show up.

You can then use t-tests to see if they are significantly different from each other. If you have a number of predeternibed catefories You are likely to test you should, for rigor anyway, decide on the comparisons anyway and hold each test to a significance level equal to your target significance level, i.e. .05, divided by the number of comparisons.

For doing all pair wise comparisons you could use Tukey's Honestly Significant Difference test.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. I was hoping that there was some way I could "extrapolate" the per-entry type given some samples, however your suggestion will also work!